# How to stop Puppeteer from overwriting duplicate downloads?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a puppeteer script that runs in a cronjob on an Ubuntu, in headless mode. (also runs with headless: false when testing it on my pc (OS X), which basically scrapes a certain webpage that dynamically loads data, based on some parameters, and downloads a whole bunch of pdfs. Problem is the files' download links are unavailable, as each file has a reference that points to the download link which is stored in a db. So the only solution i found was to hard-code the action : loop through the list of files, right click(that prompts a download button) and click download for each file (check code snippet below).

```
// get li elements with pdf files
const listdownload = await page.$$('#j_idt68 > div > #idPanelContent > div > div > #idDetaliicomunicare > div > div > div > ul > li > .ui-treenode-children  > li > span');


// loop through each element then right click + click download
    for (let iteminlistdownload of listdownload){
      await iteminlistdownload.click({button: 'right',});
      await delay(3000);
      let [viz] = await page.$x('//*[@id="idDetaliicomunicare:j_idt163"]/ul/li/a');
      viz.click().catch(e => {});
      await delay(3000);
    }
```

There can be hundreds, thousands of files and you can only imagine it is pretty hard to determine which files are duplicate. When the download happens, the duplicates don't just get renamed with (1), (2) .. etc, like it usually happens, but rather they just overwrite the previous version, which is not good, as i need every single one of them. (Same file name does not necessarily mean same content. can be same name but different content).

**Is there a way to save duplicates too?**

Comment: I don't know of a trick to make this work, but as an alternative can you just rename each file to a unique name after it downloads?

Comment: @Benny Hello there. Sorry for this late reply. I kind of gave up checking the post. Unfortunately, i can't do that, as those files are uploaded by the public beneficiaries and are property of our government (including the website i'm scraping).

Answer (score 0):

first, you should get the pdf in full screen and use the native puppeteer pdf function

```
await page.pdf({ path: 'page.pdf' });
```

name it the URL to keep track of duplicates

then you can put the puppeteer download function into a conditional statement that checks if the file with that name exists, from there you can either not download or execute a different version of the puppeteer code that renames the download path by adding or changing the path string

```
const fs = require('fs')

const path = './file.pdf'

try {
  if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // file exists and do not execute download 
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```